# Trying to select 250 lowest terms R

Tags: r, function, sorting

I am trying to create a function that takes in a set list and select the top 250 lowest terms. However, when I run the full code, there is a mistake, so I figured the mistake might be somewhere in the function to select the lowest terms.

Here is the code:

```
selFun <- function(x) 
{x == (order(x, decreasing = FALSE)[1:250])
}
```

And this is a bit of the list of data that I want to implement as x:

```
        TSPAN6           TNMD           DPM1          SCYL3       C1orf112            FGR            CFH 
  9.533633e-01   2.546213e-05   2.868157e-03   2.519265e-02   7.661085e-01   3.308286e-02   7.419554e-09 
         FUCA2           GCLC           NFYA          STPG1         NIPAL3          LAS1L          ENPP4 
  8.119698e-11   3.273434e-03   6.048925e-04   2.264826e-03   2.319325e-02   3.065685e-03   4.675599e-02
```

Comment: I think that you want `rank`  not `order`

Answer (score 1):

you could use `order` as

```
selFun <- function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x, decreasing = FALSE)[1:250]]
  x
}
```

or `sort`

```
selFun <- function(x) {
  x <- sort(x, decreasing = FALSE)[1:250]
  x
}
```

to extract the lowest 250 values.

*Note*: You used `x == ....` in your Q. To assign a value to x, use `<-`. For further information you should check `?Comparison` and `?assignOps`.
Furthermore, you have to return your result in the function. This can either be achieved by `return(x)` or by simply putting the object at the end (in these examples I simply put `x` in the last line of the function).

**Test:**

using a 10 value vector (and reducing the number of digits returned to 5):

```
x <- 10:1
```

both functions return

```
selFun(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

**EDIT**

if you want to create a logical vector which indicates these 250 lowest values you can use these values like this:

```
x %in% selFun(x)
```

which gives (with the above mentioned 10 values example):

```
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I want the top 250 to be marked true and the rest false

Comment: That is why I used ==. But, only one comes out TRUE. I want 250 to come out that way

Comment: I got it though I think

Comment: I added an example to fit the logical approach you are looking for. If it satisfies your needs, you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the dplyr package and `arrange`. I am really keen on the dplyr package:

```
arrange(iris, Petal.Length)[1:10, ]
```